# How to map a network drive on a remote system in C#

Tags: c#

I am using `MapNetworkDrive` Method of the `WshNetwork` object. I am able to map a network shared folder as a drive on my computer through the code. But my real objective is to map a network drive in a remote computer to a shared folder on my computer. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`WMI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg196675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a [remote process](http://techblog-giri-csharp.blogspot.ca/2008/10/remote-program-execution-using-c-wmi.html) and send a console [command](http://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/) to map that drive

You could also use [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) if WMI does not work for you.

Comment: Please mark as answer it works as you wish and don't need further help.

Comment: You could use PsExec as well as edited in my answer.